# 'react-google-maps' Markers keeps showing although the array is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using `react-google-maps` within my `GoogleMapComponent.js`. This component should render multiple markers based on a prop called `similarLocations`. At initial render, the array is empty, and no markers are shown on the map. Inside the parent component, when the user inputs any character, a fetch request is triggered, which responds with an array of similar locations that is passed to the `GoogleMapComponent`, and the markers are successfully displayed on the map.

However, when the user inputs another character that results in an empty array response, the previous markers continue to be displayed on the map, even though I have confirmed that the prop is being passed with an empty array. How can I remove the markers when the array is empty?
Here's the parent component `CreateLocation.js` :

```
            import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
            import Input from '../../../components/input'
            import { checkLocationMatches} from '../api'
            import GoogleMapComponent from './GoogleMapComponent'


            const CreateLocation = ({
                isEdit,
            }) => {
                const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState({
                    id: null,
                    client: null,
                    locationName: '',
                    googleLocationDetails: '',
                    nameAr: '',
                    nameEn: '',
                    street: '',
                    description: '',
                    category: null,
                    clientCode: '',
                    tags: [],
                    lat: 0,
                    lang: 0,
                    gov: '',
                    city: '',
                    area: ''
                })
                const [similarLocations, setSimilarLocations] = useState([])

                const matchArabicName = async () => {
                    try {
                        const data = {
                            lat: locationData.lat,
                            lang: locationData.lang,
                            clientId: locationData.client.value,
                            matcher: 'name_ar',
                            name: locationData.nameAr
                        }
                        const response = await checkLocationMatches(data)
                        response.data ? setSimilarLocations(response.data) : setSimilarLocations([])
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err.response, 'match err')
                    }
                }


                useEffect(() => {
                    if (locationData.lat !== 0 && locationData.nameAr.length > 0 && !isEdit) {
                        matchArabicName()
                    }
                    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
                }, [locationData.lat, locationData.nameAr])

                return (
                    <Container>
                        <Body>
                            <Form>
                                <Input
                                    disableWithBorder={false}
                                    label="Client Location Name (Arabic)"
                                    name="nameAr"
                                    placeholder="EX: Hyper one"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={locationData.nameAr}
                                    onChange={e => handleLocationDetailsChange(e)}
                                    required
                                    isEditable
                                />
                            </Form>

                            <MapContainer>
                                <GoogleMapComponent
                                    isMarkerShown
                                    containerElement={
                                        <div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }} />
                                    }
                                    setMapLocationData={handleSetMapLocationData}
                                    lat={locationData.lat}
                                    lang={locationData.lang}
                                    isOpen={true}
                                    similarLocations={similarLocations}
                                />
                            </MapContainer>
                        </Body>

                    </Container>
                )
            }

            export default CreateLocation
```

`GoogleMapComponent.js`:

```
      /* eslint-disable eqeqeq */
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
  import { compose, withProps } from 'recompose';
  import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps';
  import MapMarker from '../../../assets/icons/map-marker.svg'
  import SimilarMarkerIcon from '../../../assets/icons/similar-marker.svg'

  const GoogleMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
      googleMapURL:
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&region=EG&language=ar&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
      loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
      mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
  )(({
    isMarkerShown,
    multipleMarkers,
    similarLocations,
    readOnly
  }) => {


    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(similarLocations, 'Similar locations')
      console.log(similarLocations.length, 'Similar locations length')
    }, [similarLocations])


    const onMarkerDragEnd = (coord) => {
      const { latLng } = coord;
      const lat = latLng.lat();
      const lng = latLng.lng();
      setCurrentPosition({ lat: lat, lang: lng });
      getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng);
    };

    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={zoom || 12}
        zoom={zoom || 12}
        center={{ lat: currentPosition.lat, lng: currentPosition.lang }}
        onClick={(e) => onMarkerDragEnd(e)}>

        {isMarkerShown && !multipleMarkers && (
          <Marker
            position={{ lat: currentPosition.lat, lng: currentPosition.lang }}
            defaultDraggable={!readOnly}
            onDragEnd={(e) => onMarkerDragEnd(e)}
            options={{
              icon: {
                url: MapMarker,
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        {
          similarLocations.length > 0 &&
          similarLocations.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.location.id}
              position={{ lat: +marker.location.latitude, lng: +marker.location.longitude }}
              onClick={() => {
                handleActiveMarker(marker.location.id)
              }}
              options={{
                icon: {
                  url: SimilarMarkerIcon,
                },
              }}
              visible={similarLocations.includes(marker)}
            >
              {activeMarker === marker.location.id ? (
                <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}>
                  <div>{marker.location.name_ar}</div>
                </InfoWindow>
              ) : null}
            </Marker>
          ))
        }
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  });

  export default GoogleMapComponent;
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? A working codesandbox that demonstrates the issue would be helpful for the community so that we can check it on our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this open issue in `react-google-maps` https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/921
so simply the problem was because my app was wrapped by `<React.StrictMode>`